# Problem - Update file properties action works fine but it updates modified column with user name who is owner/publisher of workfow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am updating few document library columns through Microsoft flow but it updates modified column by user name who is published/owner of workflow. I don't want to update modified by column.

I am using "Update file properties" action.

Any alternate steps which i can do??

Answer (score 0):

I think for this You need to use REST api with method validateUpdateListItem for SP Online (which is the equivalent of systemUpdate in on-prem) which allows to update item and also allows to update 'modified' and 'modified by' column. This is a POST request. You can use HTTP request to SharePoint and do something similar like this (sorry for the lang but I have PL environment  :) )
[image]

I use this kind of REST api request

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test_flow_sysUpdate')/Items(2)/validateUpdateListItem
```

where in list 'test_flow_sysUpdate' I update item with index = 2 (here You can use a variable which will be dynamically initialized)

after that in request body I use

```
    {
    "formValues":[
    { "FieldName": "Title", "FieldValue": "flowModify" },
    {"FieldName":"Modified", "FieldValue":"09/12/2018 11:00 AM"}]
    }
```

As You see I update 'Title' column and 'Modified'... also with this You can update 'Modified by' column with the value of the user which was there before (so first You will need to get the previous user (author or if not empty editor)

the result is
[image]
even if I updated just a while ago the 'Modified' is set to 09/12/2018.

You can check the 'systemUpdate' options [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/list-items-system-update-options-sharepoint-online-andrew-koltyakov/)

and [here](http://johnliu.net/blog/2019/2/flowninja-hack-78-modifying-modified-by-and-modified-time-with-microsoft-flow) You have a step by step tutorial with similar case but he also updates the user ... so please check out how to create user type value as it is a bit tricky

Answer (score 0):

For updating Author, Editor, Modified date and created date, it is important that

1. Disable Versionning on list
2. Update fields (sequence of assignation of values is very important)
3. Enable verisonning

You can find the example of Client site PowerShell (PnP) at https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6553897844107943936